# Building geoprocessing service using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-server, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-10.4

[image]Using ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop, I am trying to build a model to be published as a service. this model should take shapefile and table as inputs and run "Join Field" tool on them then i am using "feature class to feature class" tool to save that shapefile as a featureclass in a db.
so far the service output is:
Job Status: esriJobSucceeded

Results:
None

attached the screenshot from my model
the model works fine on arcmap and i can see the feature class created in the default db. i was expecting to do the same when i run as a service, when i checked the default db on the server, couldn't find the output

i m wondering why it didn't save anything in the db ? am i missing a step ?

Comment: What were all the steps that you performed from creating it to publishing and testing it as a geoprocessing service?

Comment: created the model,saved it, closed, run as toolbox, got results in the results window, right click share as a service, enabled upload for rest service, once published i tried to call it using a GPFeatureRecordSerLayer json and submitted the job then got that results

Comment: There's an [edit] button beneath your question that should be used to provide more details. To me it seems like your question is giving too little detail, especially regarding the model and its tools and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It is a while since I have done this but it looks to me like your model may not have specified an output parameter.

If you compare your model to one in the Help page titled  [A quick tour of authoring and sharing geoprocessing services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_authoring_and_sharing_geoprocessing_services/00570000007q000000/GUID-1BC84E63-EDA2-4E57-9E3A-B1F9AF07840D/) you will see that the latter has two input and one output parameters while yours only has a single input parameter.